# UITabBarController containing UISplitViewController doesn't handle rotation on iPad correctly

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ios6.1

I’m experiencing unusual behavior on an iPad in iOS 6.1.2 when using a UITabBarController with a UISplitViewController (which has a UITableViewController for the master view controller).  If I have multiple tabs, of which at least one tab contains a split view controller, and I am in landscape mode while viewing the tab that contains the split view controller, then I switch to another tab, then move to portrait mode, then press the tab that contains the split view controller, what happens next is that the master view controller (a table view controller) will display the table view over top of the detail view, when it is clearly not supposed to be there.  This behavior happens only the first time the app is loaded, but is consistent behavior.

This scenario is easy to recreate by simply creating a project that is a split view application that uses an iPad device and Core Data (didn’t try it without using Core Data).  After the project is created, use the storyboard and add a tab bar controller and make it the initial view controller, then add a view controller seque from the tab bar controller to the split view controller.  After that, only one change is necessary in code which is to change the one line in application:didfinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate.m:

Change the following template code:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

To:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [tbc.viewControllers lastObject];
```

Perhaps I’m breaking some iOS rules, and trying to do something I’m not supposed to?  All I want to do is to be able to tab between a few different split view controllers.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this Git.

https://github.com/nalyd88/DCToolkit/tree/master/DCToolkit/DCToolkit

From what I understand the problem stems from the split view controller not updating it's orientation when it's not visible.

Here a subclassed tab view controller and split view controller are used which pass the message along.

Thanks to Dylan at http://objectiveseesharp.wordpress.com/ for this solution! I just found it.